# easy way of showing errors in a wicket form

Tags: wicket

I am a wicket beginner and find it extremely hard to implement more advanced actions in it.

So I've got a form with input fields in it and a submit button. I've written my own validator with its own logic. now when the validator fails the page simply reloads and the wrong value is lost. what I want is:

1. inputs with wrong input(where the validator failed) should be graphically different, that is get its own style - can i do it in the validator itself? or do I have to implement a visitor? how do i register it for this very form? No error message is necessary.
2. the 'wrong input' should not be lost and should be visible to the user.

I'd be eternally thankful for a simple solution (with some code snippets please)

Comment: #1 wicket:for can be used to style your label on the field that has errors.  See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket's+XHTML+tags#Wicket%27sXHTMLtags-Attributewicket:for. You need to post some code for #2, as you shouldn't be losing your invalid content.

Comment: the problem is that OnInitialize contains some code loading values into my components. is there any way to make sure that the submit button will do_nothing_ when the validation fails?

Comment: As long as you use an IValidator to validate, you shouldn't need to worry about your submit button. When you click submit, Wicket will look at required fields, convert your input, and run your validator before pushing your input to your models and entering onSubmit. If any steps fail before pushing input, onError is called instead of onSubmit. The key is to use a validator and do not validate in onSubmit.

Comment: I use a validator that I have written myself. the workflow doesn't even enter the onSubmit method and I have no validation code there. when it enters onError the "wrong" values are still there but then the workflow apparently calls OnInitialize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a Validator + Behavior.
The behavior is needed to modify the FormComponent's markup when it is invalid.

Fortunately they mix very well:

```
public class MyValidator extends Behavior implements IValidator<SomeType> {...}
```

Implement `IValidator#validate(IValidatable)` to validate (you already have this) and override `Behavior#onComponentTag(Component, ComponentTag)` to set a CSS class when invalid, e.g.:

```
@Override public void onComponentTag(Component c, ComponentTag tag) {
   FormComponent fc = (FormComponent) c;
   if (!fc.isValid()) {
     tag.append("class", "error", " ");
   }
}
```

Make sure you have a `.css` file loaded that defines `.error` with the desired styles. You can override `Behavior#renderHead(Component, IHeaderResponse response) {response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(new CssResourceReference(SomeScope.class, "res/css/styles.css")))}` for that.

I hope things a cleaner now.

Have fun!

Comment: You should add this to the examples on the Wicket website. Maybe enhance the Guestbook example with a validator, like the above.